# Maximal number of inequivalent elements in $\mathbb{E}_p$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

For a prime $p$ of the form $12k+1$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p=\{0,1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$, let 
$$ \displaystyle \mathbb{E}_p=\{(a,b) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_p,\quad  p\nmid 4a^3+27b^2\}$$
For $(a,b), (a',b') \in \mathbb{E}_p$ we say that $(a,b)$ and $(a',b')$ are equivalent if there is a non zero element $c\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $p\mid (a' -ac^4)$ and $p\mid (b'-bc^6)$. Find the maximal number of inequivalent elements in $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}_p$.

This is a problem from Korean MO but I don't know the year. I have no idea about how to proceed with it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Korea final round 2002 day 1 problem 1](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=155&cid=105&year=2002)

Comment: $4a^3+27b^2$ is the discriminant of the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3+ax+b$.  The nondivisibility requirement means that $p$ is a prime of good reduction (equiv. the curve does not have a cusp mod p$.  Not sure that any of this recognition helps.

Comment: But barto, no solution is given there, what is its use? And @Eric Towers, I think this problem has an easier solution, your idea is probably what created the problem. Thanks for the nice observation.